Opening s3 bucket with fsspec causes spyder iPython console to hang
When I run the below code in Spyder, the IPython console seems to "hang" after execution.
import fsspec

TCR_bucket_url = 's3://cires-20-century-reanalysis-v3/zarr/single-levels-space'
storage_options = {'endpoint_url': 'https://s3.us-east-1.wasabisys.com'}
TCR_store = fsspec.get_mapper(TCR_bucket_url, client_kwargs=storage_options, anon=True)

It's weird, if I run the script and then type something like print('aaa') in the console, and hit "enter", nothing happens. However, if I smash the enter button repeatedly, eventually it works.
This issue does not happen in a jupyter qtconsole or jupyter notebook or when runnign an iPython kernel directly in a command prompt window.
